# Eclipse not showing property popup windows

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, properties, popup

I am using Eclipse on Linux Mint for android development. When I select any object and view its properties, I am not able to view the pop-up window which normally appear while selecting certain properties like GRAVITY, INPUT METHOD etc. I have attached the screen shot:
[image]

even after clicking the GRAVITY property, no window appeared.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try going to the render target dropdown (which is the dropdown showing "19" above the layout towards the right) and switching to an earlier version, such as 18.

Please start these isuues

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=61695

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61715